# How to check what keyboard type is installed in MacBook Air by serial number?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, serial-number

I have unpacked MacBookAir 13". How to check using serial number or other information from the box if MacBook is equipped with English keyboard layout or with other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've compared two MBA boxes one labeled as IEA/DNK and one labeled as DNK/DNK. The first one was with International English (or if you are Polish this is Polish Pro for you) the second one was Danish layout (they have no programmer layout).

So it looks like **the first 3 letters are keyboard layout and 3 letters after slash are country code.**

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the part number?  I think the standard English keyboard model is MD231LL/A (from the Apple US online store).

Comment: The end of the number is IEA/DNK

Comment: Are you talking about the part number, which begins with MD231?